# Issue with databinding when the browser's window is minimized

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding

Hi I have a problem with a data binded property.
I have a button with the enabled attribute binded to a boolean variable

```
<mx:Button id="btnSave" width="98" label="Sauvegarder" enabled="{isEditing}" click="sendEvent(UPDATE)"/>
```

When I click on a datagrid, an event is dispatched

```
var eventL : ListEvent = new ListEvent(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK,true);
                eventL.rowIndex = listData.rowIndex;
                dispatchEvent(eventL);
```

and then I have a listener where I change the value of the binded property

```
private function onItemClick(event : ListEvent) : void {
     var encoder : Encoder = Encoder(theView.dg.dataProvider[event.rowIndex]);
     theView.isEditing = true;
    }
```

When I minimise my browser's window or put another window with windows+tab, the data binded value changes and my buttons become disabled..

ps- I'm using pure mvc and the isEditing value change occurs in the mediator

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Not enough info: the problem must be in the code that sets `isEditing`

Comment: Hi RIAstar, I have edited my first post

Comment: That's where `isEditing` is set to `true`, but where is it set to `false`?

Comment: it's on my view         [Bindable]
   public var isEditing : Boolean = false;

Comment: If you're absolutely certain that it's not set to `false` anywhere else, the only explanation can be that the view component is being completely re-created. However, that seems highly unlikely.

Comment: RIAstar, thanks you are absolutly right. When I change or reduce the browser's windows, I don't know why and Event.DEACTIVATE is triggered and it enters to another method where I have set my binding to false